# Parse xml in T-SQL like table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following xml:

```
  <product>
        <ean>1234</ean>
        <upc>1234</upc>
        <unit/>
    </product>
```

I try to parse it as the following:

```
   DECLARE @xmlCol XML = '
  <product>
        <ean>1234</ean>
        <upc>1234</upc>
        <unit/>
    </product>'

SELECT
  [upc] = x.t.value('@upc', 'int')
FROM 
  @XmlCol.nodes('/product/upc') as x(t)
  CROSS APPLY x.t.nodes( 'Value' ) AS v(t)
```

What is incorrect?

The result is empty. it Should be upc - 1234

Comment: What is the problem or error?

Comment: @jww There is no error. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45cbe5518675ef859a6d5b16ddacf507

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you looking for

```
   DECLARE @xmlCol XML = '
  <product>
        <unit>
        <ean>1234</ean>
        <upc>1234</upc>
        </unit>
    </product>'

SELECT @xmlCol.value('(/product/unit/upc)[1]', 'int') Result
```

Or even

```
DECLARE @T xml = '
  <product>
        <unit>
        <ean>1234</ean>
        <upc>12345</upc>
        </unit>
    </product>
      <product>
        <unit>
        <ean>1234</ean>
        <upc>123456</upc>
        </unit>
    </product>';

SELECT K.value('(.)[1]', 'int') UpcValue
FROM @T.nodes('/product/unit/upc') AS T(K);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please help. If I want to read this xml from file, how will it look like?

Comment: @KirillRodeonov That's another question, if you want so, please feel free to ask another question and don't forgot to mark the right answer to your question as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

seems youm missed opening unit  `<unit>` tag

```
 DECLARE @xmlCol XML = '
  <product>
      <unit>
         <ean>1234</ean>
         <upc>1234</upc>
       </unit>
  </product>'
```

Comment: It's never mind. When I delete this tag it's also not working

Comment: @jww   . thanks answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
  [upc] = x.t.value('(upc/text())[1]', 'int')
FROM 
  @XmlCol.nodes('/product') as x(t)
```

The following will also work:

```
SELECT
  [upc] = x.t.value('upc[1]', 'int')
FROM 
  @XmlCol.nodes('/product') as x(t)
```